# Fabricjs - Image applyFilters is slow and after loadFromJSON it fixes

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I use image.applyFilters feature of fabricjs. When i first load image on canvas and applied an image filter, browser blocks for a couple seconds especially for large size images upper than 2 MB. But, when i clear canvas and load it back with loadFromJSON, the problem gets fixed and image filters start to work properly without blocking browser.

Is it about fabricjs or my code, i couldnt figure out. I'll apreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

img.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));

```
    fabric.Image.fromURL(e.target.src, function(img) {
          img.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Tint());
          img.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
           canvas.add(img);
});

 canvas.deactivateAll().renderAll();
```